# SQL query question

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with airlines, airports and their routes.
I have two tables routes and complement.
The complement table was built by searching the route segments that share a node. (B is the node in the route A->B->C)

I want to build the complement table so that the destination reached through the node is unique. In other words, an airline should not be able to reach the the destination C on its own.

After building the complement table, I tried:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM complement AS t1
   , routes AS t2
WHERE t1.airline_id1 = t2.airline_id
  AND t1.source = t2.source
  AND t1.destination != t2.destination
```

*airline_id1 refers to the first airline that serves the route A to B. (In A->B->C route)
The original table had about 650,000 records, but I'm getting over 10 million records with this query. I am sure I'm doing something wrong with this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Some fields in complement table are airline_id1, airline_id2, source_airport, node, destination_airport

Comment: What is in there in the complement table? Can you give some sample data?

Comment: condition t1.destination != t2.destination seems susceptible, Can we have case like A->B->C and A->B->D. So both these records will satisfy the conditions and hence number of results will be more then actual.

Comment: If the rule is "an airline should not be able to reach the the destination C on its own." then why is this in your query: "t1.airline_id1 = t2.airline_id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `complement` table have an `airline_id2` field (for the `B->C` part of the trip)?

This will give all "complement" routes where the two parts are done by different airlines:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM complement AS c
WHERE c.airline_id1 != c.airline_id2
```

Or maybe you want:

(all "complement" routes from A to C for airlines that do not have a "direct" route from A to C).

```
SELECT c.*
FROM complement AS c
  LEFT JOIN routes AS r
    ON c.source_airport = r.source_airport
      AND c.destination_airport = r.destination_airport
      AND c.airline_id1 = r.airline_id
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, airline_id2 is the second airline that serves the route from B to C